# Fonts are rendering differently across apple devices. So frustrating

Tags: macos, fonts, css, opacity

I am hoping some of you css wizards might have run into the problem I'm about to describe.

I've created css3 buttons for a clients website, in order to replace their current image buttons. The buttons happen to be a light font face on a dark value background (white text on a red background).

On OSX and iOS, the quartz rendering engine kind of freaks out about this, and anti-aliases the font to death. Bold become really really really bold.

The strange thing is, I develop on a Mac, and cannot replicate the rendering problem the client is having across multiple devices. I've made sure I only have system fonts enabled, that my font smoothing is set the same, etc...

I found an article that suggested a fix for webkit based browsers [here](http://dave-bond.com/css/font-too-bold-on-a-mac/), and have seperated the text from it's background in order to give just the text an opacity value.

Still, no dice. Anyone have idea what could be the problem here?

**Sample image:**

[image]

Comment: What's the markup? Is it a web font? Or just a font-family declaration? If the latter, are you SURE the client has the exact same font installed on their machine?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that applying `font-weight: bold;` to an already-Bold font can make it do weird things.

Comment: I've created a sandbox page for the buttons in question at [http://thedrearlight.com/button-samples](http://thedrearlight.com/button-samples)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered bolding issues with web fonts on webkit based browsers. I used the following CSS property to remedy it:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Seems like a better solution than messing with opacity to fix font weights... which really just feels like a hack.

Comment: I tried using -webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased; before. I'll try your suggestion and see how it comes off. Thank you.